# Перевод даты из одного формата в другой через SimpleDateFormat - ParseException: Unparseable date

Tags: java, simpledateformat

Код:

```
Person person = allPeople.get(id);

// принимаем строчку Wed Dec 09 00:00:00 MSK 1998 и переводим в oldDateFormat:
String string = allPeople.get(id).getBirthDay().toString();
SimpleDateFormat oldDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MM hh:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
SimpleDateFormat newDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);

// date "забирает" на себя отформатированную ранее строку:
Date date = oldDateFormat.parse(string);
// и пробуем привести под более читабельный формат dd-MM-yyyy:
String result = newDateFormat.format(date);
Date date2 = newDateFormat.parse(result);
```

В итоге исключение:

> ParseException: Unparseable date.

Я неправильно выставил обозначения в `oldDateFormat`? Или в чём проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте `MMM`для парсинга `Dec`

Comment: Зачем вам парсить дату?

Comment: Для чего вообще нужна строчка ``Date date2 = newDateFormat.parse(result);``? Дата в нужном строковом формате уже лежит в ``result``, дата в формате даты лежит в ``date``.